# assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, pointers

Why am I getting this warnings in my `insertNode()`:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
```

in this line:

```
 head->next = newNode; //point head's next to the newNode
```

and

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
```

in this line:

```
 Node *current = head->next;
```

In my `main()` function I have also this warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'insertNode' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
```

in this line:

```
insertNode(&head, num);
```

I have a bunch of others similar to these warnings in my code. How can I fix them?

```
 typedef struct NodeStruct{
      int data;
      struct Node *next;
 }Node;

void insertNode(Node *head, int data){
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;

    if(head->next == NULL){
        head->next = newNode; 
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }

    else{
        Node *current = head->next; 
        while(current != NULL && current->data < data){
            current = current->next;
        }
        newNode->next = current->next;
        current->next = newNode; 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(NodeStruct));
    head->next = null;
    insert(head, 22);
    insert(head, 55);
    insert(head, 44);
    insert(head, 2);
    insert(head, 2112);
    insert(head, 3);


    printList(head);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you show the structure definition. And `insertNode(&head, num);` -> `insertNode(head, num);`

Comment: @haris, why should `head` be without `&` ?

Comment: Because `head` is a pointer to `Node` and thats what you are receiving in `insertNode(Node *head, int data)`

Comment: @Haris, how can I fix incompatible types though?

Comment: I think the other warnings are because of the one mistake i pointed above. Correct that and check once plz.

Comment: Also, `Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));` is much better as `Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main`-

```
insertNode(&head, num);
           ^ don't pass address
```

It expects `Node *`   , you should call it like this -

```
insertNode(head, num);
```

And other warnings are because of the above mistake as you pass address of `head` instead of passing `head` to function .

Also in `struct NodeStruct` change this -

```
struct Node *next;         // you cannot reference Node in struct itself
```

To -

```
struct NodeStruct *next;   //You need to use structure name
```

Comment: And then change `->` to `.`, @ameyCU ??

Comment: @John, No. you don't need to change that.

Comment: @John Why would that be ? `head` is still a pointer o struct.

Comment: Because now it's giving me error: `error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'Node')|` in the lines that have `->` operators. @ameyCU

Comment: @John Found that . Please take a look at answer .

Comment: @John Glad I  could help :-)